# Why is the text for the number of hats on the Winter Bash Leaderboard for SO so small in size?

Tags: discussion, bug, design, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

I was looking in the SO Winter Bash Leaderboard, and I wonder why is the number for the number of hats much smaller in size than for the whole network leaderboard:

[image]

Whereas the numbers for the SE are much bigger in size:

[image]

Is this intended, or a bug?

**Edited:**

I am sorry I mean the size of the text.

Answer (score 2):

In the SE top leaderboard, you have the following element:

```
<div class="sb-hatcount-num fs-title">
<span title="23 distinct hats across all sites, 32 hats total">23</span>
</div>
```

The class `fs-title`, has the following attribute:

```
.fs-title {
    font-size: 1.61538462rem!important;
}
```

While in the top stack overflow leaderboard, you dont have the class `fs-title`:

```
<div class="sb-hatcount-num"><span title="18 hats on Stack Overflow">18</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because not all hats are won on a single site. In example above, you've won 18 unique hats on SO and 23 unique hats on SE overall.

EDIT: On analyzing the code behind, this seems to be intentional. The developers have used `fs-title` class along with `sb-hatcount-num` for the network leaderboard page whose font-size is around 1.62 times that of the original (refer highlighted portions):

[image]

Whereas on the SO specific page (or other site specific pages), only `sb-hatcount-num` class is used which has no such overridden property for the font size:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I meant the size of the text

Answer (score 1):

On SE the size is much bigger, and another element named `div.sb-hatcount-num.fs-title`:

[image: larger]

Whereas on SO it's a different element `div.sb-hatcount-num` that is smaller:

[image: smaller]